# C# Linq to SQL: will multiple reads/writes cause prolonged locking?

Tags: linq-to-sql, locking

Suppose

- I create a Linq to SQL DataContext
- I read one record using this DataContext
- I spend ten seconds to think
- I change the record and submit the changes using this DataContext.

Are the table locked during these ten seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they would not be locked when you 'spend ten seconds to think', otherwise this would be sort of checking out rows/tables. Of course, this means that some other process could also read and write changes in those ten seconds, which could lead to concurrency issues for you.